# Prove that for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $M>0$ such that $m^* (E \setminus [-M,M]) < \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $m^*$ be the Lebesgue outer measure in $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ satisfies its outer measure is finite.

Prove that for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $M>0$ such that $m^* (E \setminus [-M,M]) < \varepsilon$.

I have a problem here. Because we don't know whether $E$ is measurable or not, so I cannot apply the continuity of measure or the inner/outer approximation to do.

All the things I have is the definition of outer measure and since $[-M,M]$ is measurable,

$$m^* (E) = m^* (E \cap [-M,M]) + m^* (E \setminus [-M,M]).$$

The textbook I used is Real Analysis by Royden and Fitzpatrick.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Since $E$  has a finite measure then it is measurable.

Comment: @IrbidMath $E$ has a finite OUTER measure, not measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\{B_{j}\}$ boxes so that $E\subseteq \bigcup B_{j}$ and $\sum |B_{j}|\leq m^{*}(E)+ 1$. Because $m^{*}(E)$ is finite, there is a big enough $N$ so that $\sum\limits_{j \geq N}|B_{j}|\leq \varepsilon$. The family $\{B_{j}\}_{j\leq N}$ is bounded, so there is a big enough $M$ so that $$\bigcup\limits_{j\leq N}{B_{j}}\subseteq [-M,M]$$
We have that $\{B_{j}\}_{j \geq N}$ covers $E\setminus [-M,M]$ so $$m^{*}(E\setminus [-M,M])\leq \varepsilon$$